# Leaflet and 3D GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, 3d, leaflet, webgl, geojson

I'm not expert...

I would like to know if exist the possibility (library or plugin) to show a GeoJOSN in 3D mode.

I'm using Leaflet.

Probably this question is too generic but I would like to know if exist something about it (start point).

In my specific case I need to show sea depth areas.